# Does mechanically transported charge generate a magnetic field?

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetic-fields, electric-current

If an object with charge of $1 \;\text{C}$ is mechanically moved from point A to point B every second, is an electrical current of $1 \;\text{A}$ generated? Will a magnetic field be generated?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, any flow of electron signifies flow of current and yes it also produces magnetic field.